# Заполнение поля texarea

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Есть `textarea`. Нужно его при клике на кнопку заполнить текстом. Как это сделать? Какая есть функция?

**html:**

```
<textarea id="input" rows="3" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
<button onClick="try_func()">Button!</button>
```

**js:**

```
var text = "data";
function try_func() {
    //???
}
```

Я новичок. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
function try_func() {
    var area = document.getElementById('input');// получаем элемент с id input
    area.value = "data"; // заносим текст в элемент
}
</script>

<textarea id="input" rows="3" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
<button onClick="try_func()">Button!</button>
```